# jquery loop through UL while user is on page

Tags: jquery, html-lists

Is there a good way to loop through A List UL with jquery. As long as the user is on this page i want it to continue to loop, with effect like fadeIn, delay etc. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You will have to explain better what you want. "Loop through UL" makes very little sense. Zero sense actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could to it, even it makes no sense to me (yet):

```
setTimteout('loopUl()', 100);

function loopUl() {
  $('#yourUlIdentifier li').each(function () {
    $(this).doFancyStuff();
  });
  setTimeout('loopUl()', 100);
}
```

Comment: This would not work becuase after it runs the second timeout its complete.

Comment: Then you can use recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plugin. Most examples on the page are with images, but you can use any list of html elements to if you like

Comment: looks interesting, I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout` to call a function in a certain time interval then select your ul,li,a with 
jsquery selector such as `$(".divClass ul").fadeIn("slow");`